# decorationbox in appbar with special background

Tags: flutter, flutter-appbar

I am a beginner Flutter developer
I am going to implement a program similar to the picture below
This part of the appbar is an application that I planned to implement using the decoration box, but I did not succeed

[image: appbar picture]

[image: preview full page]

```
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.red[700],
    actions: [getAppbarActions()],
  ),
Widget getAppbarActions() {
  return Expanded(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: DecoratedBox(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            child: Row(
              // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                Image(
                  image: AssetImage('images/1.png'),
                  width: 40,
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  // height: 15,
                ),
                Text(
                  'hi',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ),
                // Text('hi'),
                // Text('hi'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually you dont need the use appbar to achieve the desired behaviour. You can simply pass Stack() widget to Scaffold's body parameter.

[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhA0t.png)

[scrollable Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeyJV.png)

Such as :

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          //Stack for your desired behaviour
          SizedBox(
            height: 220,

            //stack
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  height: 150,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    width: double.maxFinite,
                    height: 120,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                            blurRadius: 10),
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                          spreadRadius: -2,
                          blurRadius: 5,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        //this part is your asset and the other part of the container childrens
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: FlutterLogo(
                            size: 80,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 32.0, vertical: 8),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                "Hi",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "Hi",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),


          /// REST of your code
        Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                height: 80,
                child: Center(child: Text("Content Number ${index}")));
          },
        ),
      )
       
       
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Second Approach :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          //Stack for your desired behaviour
          SizedBox(
            height: 220,

            //stack
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  height: 150,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    width: double.maxFinite,
                    height: 120,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                            blurRadius: 10),
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                          spreadRadius: -2,
                          blurRadius: 5,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        //this part is your asset and the other part of the container childrens
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: FlutterLogo(
                            size: 80,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 32.0, vertical: 8),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                "Hi",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "Hi",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                  children: _faqData
                      .map(
                        (e) => Container(
                          height: 100,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                                  blurRadius: 10),
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                                spreadRadius: -2,
                                blurRadius: 5,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList()),
            ),
          )

          /// REST of your code
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your guidance
But I need this code to be implemented in the app bar section because the body should be used for other content
(The photo of the full image was added to the question)I need the appbar to be fixed but the page content to be scrollable

Comment: Still there is no need for appbar. You can use Listview or another scrollable widget in //Rest of code section. The Stack widget acts as a appbar like your expected behaviour. But care if you using ListView in a Column it needs to wrapped by Expanded widget. Otherwise it will crashed.

Comment: I edit the code for example usecase. You can check the second link and code.

Comment: Thank you very much burakcetn
This is great
I have just one more question. The distance of the first object from the list is too high and there is a lot of empty space. How can I reduce this space?

Comment: probably it comes from listview.builder. To eliminate the behaviour I write second approach to answer. You can check it out